# How to generate a boolean with p probability using C rand() function?

Tags: c, random

How can I generate a random boolean with a probability of `p` (where 0 <= p <= 1.0) using the C standard library `rand()` function?

i.e.

```
bool nextBool(double probability)
{
    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
bool nextBool(double probability)
{
    return (rand() / (double)RAND_MAX) < probability;
}
```

or (after seeing other responses)

```
bool nextBool(double probability)
{
    return rand() <  probability * ((double)RAND_MAX + 1.0);
}
```

Comment: The second one might actually be faster.  They're mathematically identical.

Comment: That needs to be `probability * (RAND_MAX + 1)` - otherwise, passing a value of `1.0` as `probability` will result in the function returning 0 sometimes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed a minor issue in your second version, as the `+1` generated an integer overflow

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean generate a random variable so that p(1) = p and p(0) = (1-p)?

If so, compare the output of `rand()` to `p*RAND_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

The following generator should not be biased, given rand() efficiently uniform and independent:

```
bool nextBool(double probability)
{
    double p_scaled = probability * (RAND_MAX+1) - rand();
    if ( p_scaled >= 1 ) return true;
    if ( p_scaled <= 0 ) return false;
    return random_bool( p_scaled );
}
```

Note, that while function is recursive,

1. probability of the recursive call is `1.0/RAND_MAX`, i.e quite small,
2. it has to be recursive or in some other way call `rand()` multiple times, if you want to use `probability` different from multiples of `1.0/RAND_MAX`.

Also note, that the probability is still a little bit biased. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362175/can-rand-in-c-be-used-to-generate-unbiased-bools) question.