# Random uppercase - lowercase

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uppercase, lowercase

I'd like to let a string change letters to lowercase or uppercase randomly(in Xcode).
for example: "example" to "ExaMpLe" or "eXAMPle" or ExAmPlE" or something else like this randomly..
hot can i solve this?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which part are you struggling with?  Random number generation, or converting characters to uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSString` has both a `lowercaseString` and `uppercaseString` method. You can iterate over the characters in a string as a sequence of substrings, using some random source to call the appropriate lower/upper case on each of them, collecting the result. Something like...

```
NSMutableString result = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [myString length]; i++)
{
  NSString *substring = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
  [result appendString:(rand() % 2) ? [substring lowercaseString]
                                    : [substring uppercaseString]];
}
```

You may prefer a better source of entropy than `rand`, but it'll do for an example (don't forget to seed it if you use this case as is). If the strings are large, you can do it in-place on an `NSMutableString`.

Answer (score 2):

You could either use the `-uppercaseString` and `-lowercaseString` methods on substrings, or use the `toupper()` and `tolower()` functions on characters. There's no way to simply filter a string; you'll want to use either an `NSMutableString` or a C array of characters.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771551/how-to-generate-a-boolean-with-p-probability-using-c-rand-function) for how to get a random boolean value, which you can use to decide whether a character should be uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You could break the word into an array of letters, and loop over this using a random number to determining case, after looping the array, simply stick the letters back together using NSMutableString.

NSString had a uppercaseString and lowercaseString methods you can use.