# How can I process a command in determined probability in C?

Tags: c++, c, command, probability

I would like to process a command like the way, that if I press  character A, make the corresponding command in e.g 15% of the cases. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should look into the rand() function and try for yourself. Then if you encounter specific problems you can ask here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a boolean with p probability using C rand() function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771551/how-to-generate-a-boolean-with-p-probability-using-c-rand-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to generate a random number when A is pressed.

EDIT:  For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

if(PressedA){
    int random=(rand() % 100); // random is in [0,99]
    if(random < 15){
        command();
    }    
}
```

Comment: That's correct unless rand() generates not randomly distributed value (I don't know whether it's true or not, so I used definitely _uniform_ distribution:) )

Comment: rand() generates a uniform distribution, but it's definitely more clear to explicitate that. Good point!

Comment: Note that `rand % X` will not be particularly uniform if `X` is close to `RAND_MAX`, but 100 is tiny in comparison, so it doesn't make any significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, I guess. (compile with `-std=c++11`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(0, 99);
    int x = d(rd);
    if (x < 15)
    {
        std::cout << "you, lucky boy! " << x << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```