# Can `rand()` in c++ be used to generate unbiased bools?

Tags: c++, debugging, random

I have written the following function

```
bool random_bool(double probability)
{
    double p_scaled = probability * (RAND_MAX+1) - rand();
    if ( p_scaled >= 1 ) return true;
    if ( p_scaled <= 0 ) return false;
    return random_bool( p_scaled );
}
```

Given, that `rand()` generates a number from uniform distribution on `{0,1,...,RAND_MAX-1,RAND_MAX}` and numbers from subsequent calls can be treated as independent for all practical purposes except cryptography, this should return `true` with probability `p`: two `if` statements return `true` with probability slightly below `p`, and `false` with the probability slightly above `1-p`, while the recursive call deals with everything else.

However the following test fails:

```
long long N = 10000000000; //1e10
double p = 10000.0 / N;
int counter = 0;
for (long long i=0;i<N;i++) if (random_bool(p)) counter++;
assert(9672 < counter && counter <= 10330);
```

The assert statement is designed to fail only in 0.1% of cases. However it fails all the time (with `counter` being between 10600 and 10700).

What's wrong?

**P.S.:** I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771551/how-to-generate-a-boolean-with-p-probability-using-c-rand-function) question, but it doesn't help...

Comment: note that your 2 `if`s are not taking care of all the numbers in the range `]0,1[`; you probably want to rethink the entire code and what it does. Just use a `Bernoulli PRNG`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: if I would just `return rand() < probability*(RAND_MAX+1.0)`, then I would get `true` from this function once every `1.0/32768` attempts (on average) even for `probability = 1.0e-100`, which would be unusable for my purposes.

Comment: @user2485710: Yes, my two `if`s are not taking care of all the possible numbers, returned by `rand()`. That's why I have `return` statement at the end, which is called with a small probability about `1.0/RAND_MAX`.

Comment: your way of writing and thinking about this is fundamentally wrong, just think about the fact that you declared `double` as the return type when in 2 case out of 3 you are returning a `bool`.

Comment: @user2485710: Sorry for the confusion, that was a misprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common defect in random number generators is a slight bias towards smaller results (basically a slight bias towards 0 in high order bits). This often happens when wrapping the RNG internal state to the output range is done using a simple mod, which is biased against high values unless RAND_MAX is a divisor of the size of the internal state. Here's a typical biased mapping implementation:

```
static unsigned int state;

int rand() {
   state = nextState(); /* this actually moves the state from one random value to the next, eg., using a LCG */
   return state % RAND_MAX;  /* biased */
}
```

The bias occurs because lower values output an have one more mapping under mod from the state.  E.g., if the state can have values 0-9 (10 values), and RAND_MAX is 3 (so values 0-2), then the `% 3` operation results in, depending on the state

```
Output  State
0       0 3 6 9 
1       1 4 7
2       2 5 8
```

The result 0 is over-represented because it has a 4/10 chance of being selected, vs 3/10 for the other values.

As an example with more likely values, if the internal RNG state is a 16-integer, and `RAND_MAX` is 35767 (as you mentioned it is on your platform), then all the values [0,6000] will be be output for 3 different state values, but the remaining ~30,000 values will only be output for 2 distinct state values - a significant bias. This kind of bias would tend to cause your counter value to be higher than expected (since smaller than uniform returns from rand() favors the `p_scaled >= 1` condition.

It would help if you could post the exact implementation of rand() on your platform. If it turns out to be bias in the high bits, you may be able to eliminate this by passing the values you get from rand() through a good hash function, but a better approach is probably just to use a high quality source of random numbers, e.g., the [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister)
. A better generator will also have a larger output range (effective, a higher RAND_MAX), which means your algorithm will suffer fewer retries/less recursion.

Even if the Visual Studio runtime implementation suffers from this defect, it is worth noting that it was probably at least partly an intentional design choice - using a RAND_MAX like 35767 that is relatively prime to the state size (typically a power of 2), ensures better randomness of the lower bits, since the % operation effectively mixes the high and low order bits - and having biased/non-random low order bits is often a bigger problem in practice than a slight bias in the high order bits because of the ubiquity of the caller of `rand()` reducing the range using %, which effectively uses only the low order bits for moduli which are powers of 2 (also very common).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in Linux and the results were actually pretty decent. However, it seems like you are in Windows where `RAND_MAX` is around 32768 probably. I'm saying since gcc complained in Linux that `RAND_MAX+1` results in integer overflow so I had to add a cast.

So the problem is most likely that either `RAND_MAX` is too small or the implementation of `rand()` on your system is not very good.

If the source of the problem is the implementation of `rand()`, your only option would be to change to another function from a better library. However, if the problem is the first one, you might be able to solve it as follows.

```
/* change `rand()` to return two concatenated rands */
typedef long long rand_type; /* this type depends on your actual system, you might get away with `int` */
#define BIGGER_RAND_MAX ((RAND_MAX + 2) * RAND_MAX)
rand_type bigger_rand(void)
{
    return (rand_type)rand() * (RAND_MAX + 1) + rand();
}
```

And then try your program with this rand that has a higher range. If the problem persists, most likely it's your `rand()` function that is far from random.

---

Side note: your `random_bool` should return `bool`, not `double`! Since you are checking a `double` against zero, that could also be the source of the problem, where you have false positives because the double could be not exactly zero.

Comment: a double *can be* exactly zero. it would be a shame if it couldn't be.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, of course it _can_ be. But it could also be _almost_ zero. Unlikely in this case since it's being returned as `false` and not computed upon, but anyway it's best to avoid comparing `double`s against exact numbers.

Comment: unlikely?? it's going to be *exactly zero*....  and yes, obviously, that function should have returned a `bool`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, you are absolutely right. I used unlikely to be a bit conservative, since people usually end up posting a simpler version of their actual code, in which they could have done any other wrong things. Let's drop this conversation, I assure you I also understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @Shahbaz: I was running this in Windows and RAND_MAX was 35767 indeed. However I accounted for the finite RAND_MAX and in theory my function seems to work just right. But only in theory. Let me explain: Imagine (RAND_MAX+1)-based number system, so each digit is from 0 to RAND_MAX. What I do is essentially generating a real number in [0,1], generating each digit using rand(), and if it is less than probability --- returning true. This might seem to call rand() infinitely many times, but in fact it doesn't: in most cases I need just the first digit. Why doesn't this theory work?

Comment: @fiktor, I honestly don't know. That's why I suggested a way to experiment with it. If you artificially increase `RAND_MAX` and the problem persists, then Windows' `rand()` sucks (not a surprise from Microsoft). If it the problem goes away, well then either concatenating the two `rand()`s resulted in a more uniform `rand()` function or the problem was really `RAND_MAX` being too small. Most likely though, it's `rand()` in Windows that sucks.

Answer (score 0):

i think this function's result is relate to the RAND_MAX value, in this case p = 1e-6 , if RAND_MAX equal 9999 then this will never return true

Comment: I think it will. Let `p=1e-6`, `RAND_MAX=9999`. Then with probability `1.0/10000` `rand()` will return 0. In this case both `if`s will fail, so the function will call itself recursively with `p = 1e-6 * 10000 = 0.01`. On the second attempt it will return `true` if `rand()` will return something from `{0,...,99}` and `false` otherwise, giving the total probability of `true` equal to `(1.0/10000)*(100/10000)=1e-6`. In theory.

Comment: em..you are right.I am afraid that this `rand()` function can generate   `[0,RAND_MAX]` randomly.